# How to generate similar polyhedron?

Tags: geometry, math-history, polyhedra

I'm not a matematician and I hope my question is clear enough.

I've found some super interesting (at least to me) old images of polyhedron and I want to reproduce them.

I found them in [this website](http://bibliodyssey.blogspot.com/2009/08/jamnitzer-perspectiva.html) from the old [Perspectiva Corporum Regularium](https://books.google.it/books?id=su-C9hQrR_IC&dq=Perspectiva%20Corporum%20Regularium&pg=PP5&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Perspectiva%20Corporum%20Regularium&f=false) book. To be clear the original source is this [code respository](https://github.com/levskaya/polyhedronisme).

I've tried to reproduce the above images with [Conway polyhedron notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polyhedron_notation) with this [interactive website](http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/) but I didn't manage to.

I'm curious if anyone can help me in understanding the Conway notation to reproduce those images:

[image]
[image]

## EDIT:

As noted in comments not all of the previous shapes can be done with conventional "conway notation" because it normally operates on convex polyhedra so my question is: are there any known notation to express those figures?

Comment: Doesn't the Conway notation apply only to convex polyhedra? Most of the ones in your illustration are not convex.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes! I was wrong because the interactive demo I posted has some other "experimental operators", try for example the formulas `n3T` or `lT`